# How to add double quotes to strings in csv using Python

Tags: python, csv

I have set data in a CSV file and I want to add double quotes to text and alphanumeric data, with the remaining integer, float and decimals not in double quotes.

Can any one help on this?

Sample data:

```
1, 3434, 789459 ,bdgvdjhjdhf, nagesd232 ,2yuyfudyf, #123 abc calony bangalore
```

The expected result would be:

```
1, 3434, 789459 ,"bdgvdjhjdhf", "nagesd232" ,"2yuyfudyf", "#123 abc calony bangalore"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Python's [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html) module as follows:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', newline='') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:

    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, skipinitialspace=True)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

    for row_input in csv_input:
        row_output = []
        for col in row_input:
            try:
                row_output.append(int(col))
            except ValueError, e:
                row_output.append(col)

        csv_output.writerow(row_output)
```

This reads each row in from `input.csv` and attempts to convert each entry in an `int`. If this fails it is stored as a string. Each row is then written to `output.csv`, giving the following type of output:

```
1,3434,789459,"bdgvdjhjdhf","nagesd232 ","2yuyfudyf","#123 abc calony bangalore"
```

If your csv also contains columns in `float` format, the following approach can be used:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', newline='') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, skipinitialspace=True)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

    for row_input in csv_input:
        row_output = []
        for col in row_input:
            try:
                row_output.append(int(col))
            except ValueError, e:
                try:
                    row_output.append(float(col))
                except ValueError, e:
                    row_output.append(col)

        csv_output.writerow(row_output)
```

If Python 2.x is being used, use:

```
with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
```

Comment: I've been searching for a solution like this! I can get this to work on a single file, but I'm trying to iterate it through a directory of files (about 600). Is it possible to do this? I have a question open here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55369361/python-quote-strings-in-multiple-csvs-and-merge-files-together

Answer (score 0):

```
input_data = '1, 3434, 789459 ,bdgvdjhjdhf, nagesd232 ,2yuyfudyf, #123 abc calony bangalore'
output = []
for i in input_data.split(','):
    i = i.strip()
    if not i.isnumeric():
        output.append('"%s"' % i)
    else:
        output.append(i)
print(', '.join(output))
```

Comment: You should explain your solution, not just post a block of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can check what class have any of your values:

```
list_val = [1, 3434, 789459 ,bdgvdjhjdhf, nagesd232 ,2yuyfudyf, #123 abc calony bangalore]
for i in list_val:
    if i.__class__ = str:
    .....
```